# Wierd shading of nomals

Tags: shaders, normals

Ok I have no idea what is happening here. The back side of my faces shine through the face in front. I activated "show face normals" so it is better to see. First I thought my typology is mto bad, but it even shows up on a simple cube.I may change something I'm not aware of... 
I would appreciate your help.[image]

Comment: Looks like Z fighting. Check for duplicate objects in the Outliner.

Comment: That was not the case. : (I've hidden everything except 1 object, the closer the view, the less artefacts I get.

Comment: can you upload the .blend so we can have a look at it https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The File is to big. And as it seems it is shredded. objects are not showing up after unhiding them.

Comment: Can you remove objects and materials and anything else making the file large so only the issue remains and then upload that?

Comment: I deleted most of the objects that's what is left. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6518" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6518/)

Comment: Disable the Solidifier Modifer on the Gehäuse2. Looks like the modifier was creating Z-Fighting faces.

Comment: that is dooing the trick but if I zoom out problems still accur. And as shown in the screen even a fresh added cube gets the problem. I would assume my file is corruped :/

Comment: I see what you mean. Maybe start a new file and import everything in one by one until you hit the problematic item.

Comment: Seems like it has something to do with the MatCap lighting. Studio is working way better.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone gets the same problem. I've got the reason and solution.
The shading issue is caused by a very low clip start value of the viewport while beeing zoomed out. Sub-D and Solidify making it even worse.
So nothing crashed just keep the setting high enough if you want to zoom out^^